# Add values to array using "template"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6

I'm not sure if the title is describing exactly what I want to achieve.
Simply put:

If I have 6 inputs:

> 1. Input1:  String1
> 2. Input2:  String1Count

---

> 3. Input3:  String2
> 4. Input4:  String2Count

---

> 5. Input5:  String3
> 6. Input6:  String3Count

I want to add each string to array, by number of times specified by string's respective count. When this is done and there are still fields in the array that are empty, to loop the values again and repeat it until the array is full.

Something like this

```
public string str1 = "First String";
public int String1Count = 4;

public string str2 = "Second String";
public int String2Count = 7;

public string str3 = "Third String";
public int String3Count = 5;

int[] arr1 = new int[100];


for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
  arr1[i] = str1;
  arr1[i+1] = str1;
  arr1[i+2] = str1;
  arr1[i+3] = str1;
  arr1[i+4] = str1;
  arr1[i+5] = str2;
  arr1[i+6] = str2;
  arr1[i+7] = str2;
  ...
  arr1[arr1.lenght] = str; //It may be str1, str2 or str3, whichever is next
}
```

I think at least one more `for loop` and some `if` statements are needed, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: That loop is going to give you an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Additionally, you can't assign strings to an array of `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can't assign a `string` to an `int[]` array. You have to assing it to an `string[]` array. To solve your problem you can use the modulo `%` operator:

```
string str1 = "First String";
int String1Count = 4;

string str2 = "Second String";
int String2Count = 7;

string str3 = "Third String";
int String3Count = 5;

string[] arr1 = new string[100];

int sum12 = String1Count + String2Count;
int sum123 = String1Count + String2Count + String3Count;

for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % sum123 < String1Count)
        arr1[i] = str1;
    else if (i % sum123 < sum12)
        arr1[i] = str2;
    else if (i % sum123 < sum123)
        arr1[i] = str3;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/io6eTl)**

Answer (score 0):

May be something like:

```
        string str1 = "First String";
        int String1Count = 4;

        string str2 = "Second String";
        int String2Count = 7;

        string str3 = "Third String";
        int String3Count = 5;


        var resultList = new List<String>();
        resultList.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(str1, String1Count));
        resultList.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(str2, String2Count));
        resultList.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(str3, String3Count));

        string[] resultArray = resultList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Your code only creates an array that has 16 elements, the OP asked to fill an array of 100 elements. When the first 16 elements are assigned continue filling the array.